# R lubridate: only showing last element in new variable

Tags: r, lubridate

Another newbie question, I'm afraid.  I'm trying to create new variables with "lubridate" and have run into 3 issues.

I start with a variable "time" imported as a factor in the format H:MM:SS or HH:MM:SS.  I also created "timeC" as a character.

*1. Display issue*

```
    temp$time2 <- hms(temp$time) #take my original variable "time" and convert
```

Problem:  only the seconds portion of "time2" displays on the screen, although it appears to be correct "under the hood":

```
 time2
 ----
  4

> temp$time2[1,]
[1] "7H 0M 4S"
```

*2. Extract hours Issue*

```
     temp$hour <- hour(temp$time2) #extract just the hours portion
```

Problem:  this works intermittently; sometimes it's fine, sometimes I get the following error:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

This is concerning to me because this doesn't seem like the kind of message lubridate should be throwing.

*3. Extract hour and minutes Issue*

```
temp$hourMins <- hm(temp$time2)
```

Problem:  every value of hourMins is "NA"

I've probably invested 4+ hours trying to figure this out and am wondering if there is another package that can support what I'm trying to do.

Any advice would be most appreciated.  Thanks in advance and regards!

Comment: I think you're confusing parsing a string into a time (i.e. `hms()` and `hm()`) with extracting components from that time (`hours()`, `minutes()`, `seconds()`)

Comment: @hadley - quite right your are (as you would be); still getting the hang of R documentation:  complete, but sometimes hard to tell "what matters" and what's under the hood/not important for day to day use.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a "toy" data for illustration,

```
require(lubridate)
temp <- data.frame(time=factor(c("01:01:01","02:02:02","03:03:03")))
temp$time2 <- hms(temp$time)
temp

##       time    time2
## 1 01:01:01 1H 1M 1S
## 2 02:02:02 2H 2M 2S
## 3 03:03:03 3H 3M 3S
```

**1) Display issue**

You need `attach`

```
attach(temp)
## The following objects are masked from temp (position 3):

##     time, time2

time2
## [1] "1H 1M 1S" "2H 2M 2S" "3H 3M 3S"

## detach(temp) # after final use.
```

Otherwise, the `time2` is the variable already in the environment, not the column of `temp`.

Edit: You may check with `str`to see what are exactly in your `time2`.

```
str(time2)
## Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
##   ..@ .Data : num [1:3] 1 2 3
##   ..@ year  : num [1:3] 0 0 0
##   ..@ month : num [1:3] 0 0 0
##   ..@ day   : num [1:3] 0 0 0
##   ..@ hour  : num [1:3] 1 2 3
##   ..@ minute: num [1:3] 1 2 3
```

If your `time2` has a similar structure but only the "seconds" part shows when you typing `time2`, which means your print function for this type of objects has been overridden by accident.

**2) Extract hours Issue**

```
temp$hour <- hour(temp$time2)
```

No problem

**3) Extract hour and minutes Issue**

```
time3 <- gsub("^(.+):[^:]+$","\\1",as.character(temp$time))
time3
## [1] "01:01" "02:02" "03:03"

hm(time3)
## [1] "1H 1M 0S" "2H 2M 0S" "3H 3M 0S"
```

Or use {hms} directly to include seconds as well,

```
hms(temp$time)
## [1] "1H 1M 1S" "2H 2M 2S" "3H 3M 3S"
```

Comment: Hi, @xb. - thank you for the quick response.  The good news: when I try your code for 1) as follows:      > xb <- data.frame(time=factor(c("01:04:01","1:05:10", "02:06:11", "2:07:12","03:08:13","3:09:14")))    it works perfectly.  Unfortunately, I haven't gotten it to work on the full dataframe.  I also pulled just the time column out of the full dataframe and created it as a separate dataframe.  I'm getting the same problem - just the seconds showing.  The file is 630000 rows.  I'll keep working on this...thanks again!

Comment: @user2621147, have your tried with `str` as suggested in my edit above?

Comment: I'm also not sure I share your comfort with "hour" only working intermittently :-)

Comment: Noooooooooooo, don't use attach.

Comment: @hadley Though I am not a fan of `attach`, it is handy and does no harm when a local environment is clearly scoped. AND I did mention to `detach` when close.